# How to Logout user after resetting the password

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce

I want my user to logout after they reset their password from my account page.

I have tried to reset cookies, tried wp-logout method.. It worked for few tests I have done then again, it's not working..

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: I tried it with multiple of hooks and by checking isset(if($_Post[submit])) then wp_redirect but that also doesn't work in my case

Comment: @HritikPandey Please accept the answer that's correct. The [SOLVED] tag in the headline is not how we mark answered questions on stack overflow.

Comment: @naufalibrahim i have resolved this issue in my way and added the answer below. U may check it with your code. that's correct and mark it as correct answer too

Answer (score 0):

You can try by redirecting the user to the logout page link if their password reset is successful using

wp_redirect ()

Comment: Is there any hook to use where I can check that whether the password is successfully reset? I tried with hooks but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

After trying so many ways to do this, finally changed in `"class-wc-form-handler.php"` file in woocommerce plugin under `"includes"` folder.  Or you can also override this in your `functions.php` Under "`public static function save_account_details()`" use `wp_logout();` before  "`wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) );`"